# Using unity as a render engine for 2D games

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Is it possible to use Unity as a render engine? I have a game which is written in C# and I would very much want to rewrite it to use Unity because of it's portability and use of C#. The game itself is a 2D maze game (think Pac-man).

I read alot of tutorials for using Unity for 2D games but all of them used almost only menus and editors which embedded in Unity and used only small portion with C# or other programming language. If I'm going to go down this road it means I need to "rewrite" my whole game logic with Unity's editors/menus/managers etc...

I'm looking to use it like the XNA library for example. Is there any way to achieve that with Unity? If not, is there another game engine/library using C# which is cross-platform and canm be run under mobile devices?

Answer (score -1):

I made Fangz (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6-5D6IkD5E) using Unity. If that doesn't prove that a complex 2d game can be made in Unity, I don't know what does :).

You can use Unity like XNA, but that would deny you from Unity's strengths. Once you get used to visualising your member variables in an editor in a custom way (via inspector editor scripts) it'll be hard to go back :).

Furthermore Unity now has native 2d support, which is as good is not better as 2d Toolkit, once of the most well designed 2d packages I've had the pleasure of working with.

Another advantage of Using Unity is that you'll be able to easily add animations to your 2d game. Just add an animation component, press record and move.

All in all I find myself thinking the other way around: how can anyone do a 2d game in anything other that Unity :).

Comment: Since my game is already written I would really prefer to use Unity like XNA. I played around with Unity and it seems that to write the game in the "Unity way" will require more of a complete redesign on the game engine instead of just re re-implementing the render interface. You have any resource or guideline which explains how to use Unity this way?

Comment: Sure! Take a look at Futile: https://github.com/MattRix/Futile

You'll feel at home :).

Pivvot (http://www.148apps.com/news/whitaker-trebellas-long-voyage-completing-game-pivvot/) was made using this framework.